white circle appeared covering the box after I added showDialog in flutter
After I added showDialog to my flutter code, the dialog worked fine but a white circle appeared and covered the container box

child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('Normal'),
                            content: Text(
                              'Tegangan 4 V\nArus 2 A\n',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                         ),
                        );
                      }
                 );
               },


Your problem direct solution is to assign ElevatedButton.styleFrom with transparent background color and zero elevation to style parameter of ElevatedButton
style:ElevatedButton.styleFrom( elevation:0,backgroundColor:Colors.transparent,),

note: child parameter is required, so you could pass empty Container().
see the code in this image
Actually, there is a better solution by using InkWell or GestureDetector instead of ElevatedButton and if you want specific features like elevation and shadows on-hover you can pass it manually, this way your widget works more efficient and without unnecessarily child Container
